# Conditional font color changing in query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, colors, conditional-statements, sapb1

We're using an ERP system "SAP Business One" and by do some querying, I would like to format the result font color in different colors based on specific conditioning, is there's a way to do so?

SQL Server 2014

Regards,

Comment: does your SAP  renders as html? if yes that's pretty easy, if not you should better explain

Comment: This isn't related to sql server, sql server only holds your data, is has nothing to do with formatting that data.

Comment: What SQL Server tool do you use to query SAP B1?